# How to display/show multiple div elements one by one using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple div elements in a HTML page. These divs are animating one window scroll. The problem is when I scroll the scroll bar, all the divs are animated at once. I don't want this. If the scroll bar reaches a specific position, I want a single div animated and after this, a second div should animate and so on. In other words, I want to animate multiple divs one by one on window scroll. I am using custom animation.
My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y < 500) {
   $('.demo').addClass('intro');
}
else{
   $('.demo').addClass('fadeInUp');
}
});


});
```

My CSS code with custom animation:

```
.intro{
    opacity:0;
}
.styling {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto ;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpA {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
    100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
}

@keyframes fadeInUpA {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

100% {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: none;
   -ms-transform: none;
   transform: none;
}
}

.fadeInUp {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpA;
    animation-name: fadeInUpA;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

My HTML code is following

```
<body>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>
    <div  class="intro styling demo"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are adding class to all your divs at once. First check if the div is visible after scroll and then add class to that div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
   animate();
  });
  
  animate();
  
  function animate() {
  var $divs = $(".demo");
    $.each($divs, function() {
      if (isVisible(this)) {
        $(this).addClass('fadeInUp');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('intro');
      }
    });
  }

  function isVisible(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }
});
```

```css
.intro {
  opacity: 0;
}

.styling {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpA {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUpA {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpA;
  animation-name: fadeInUpA;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
  <div class="intro styling demo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: suppose these div elements are present within a container and some other elements are also present after this container. Now, these div elements should animate within a container. Means on scroll div should be animate within a container but not outside .

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be aware of each `div` position on scroll, consider using `$('.intro').offset().top` to get an element position relative to the document. Also, the height of each `div` must be considered in order to know if `$(this).scrollTop()` is getting closer to an element.

I would suggest you to use a plugin to achieve this: https://wowjs.uk/

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i don't want to use any plugin.Suppose these div elements are present within a container and some other elements are also present after this container. Now, these div elements should animate within a container. Means on scroll div should be animate within a container but not outside

Answer (score 0):

If you seek a good solution I recommend [animejs](https://animejs.com/). But if you want to do it by yourself you can just simply get all your elements and add your animation class through a loop:

```
const elements = documents.querySelectorAll('.intro');

elements.forEach(el => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  el.classList.add('fadeInUp')
 }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a fixed version for you, not 100% sure if this is what you wanted, let me know if something is wrong.

The problem with your `divs` animating all at one time is that they all had same `animation-delay`, so I fixed that by commenting it out inside `css` and adding custom `animation-delay` to each `div`, as you will see in my code, so basically, each `div` now has 0.5s longer `animation-delay` then the previous one.

Let me know if it worked :)

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/dypRQYz

Comment: actually, buddy, I want to animate div on windows scroll. Means if I scroll window, div should animate but if I don't scroll they will not animate. I checked your solution, it is animating all div on a single scroll.

Comment: I understand. You would have to use jQuery offset() method to get the distance between each of the divs and top of the page, and then show each div only when you scroll to his offset.